# Serialize C# Objects while maintaining object references

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, save

So I have multiple custom classes which are referencing other classes in their instances. I know how serialization works in general, but how do I deal with object references? The goal is to save the objects in either xml or binary so that the state can be restored later.

In this simplified example Persons are identified by id and have a list of other Person objects referenced called friends.

```
public class Person{
      public int id;
      public List<Person> friends;

}
```

How do i serialize and deserialize this example and keep the object references intact? Also  I think deserialization can be tricky if it's trying to restore refernces to Persons that haven't been deserialized yet.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to send and receive these objects?

Comment: Just saving/loading them locally (to file) in either xml or binary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[XmlRootAttribute("Person")]
public class Person{
    [XmlAttribute("_id")]
    public int id;
    [XmlElement("friends")]
    public List<Person> friends;
}
```

And then use XmlSerializer class to create a xml file and / or your object
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa.aspx

Comment: Very cool, I did not know about the `_id` attribute. I just tested it with my code from my answer and "Bob's firend, scott's friend" returns true. (however I had to make the object I serialized a `Person` instead of a `List<Person>` and I passed in `bob` instead of `people`).

Answer (score 1):

You can track references if you piggyback on WCF and use the `DataContract` attribute and set [`IsReference = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.isreference.aspx), you then need to use the [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to serialize your data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace SandboxConsole
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var bob = new Person {Id = 0};
            var scott = new Person {Id = 1};
            var dave = new Person {Id = 2};

            bob.Friends.Add(scott);
            bob.Friends.Add(dave);
            scott.Friends.Add(dave);

            var people = new List<Person>();
            people.Add(bob);
            people.Add(scott);
            people.Add(dave);

            using (var fs = File.Create("Test.xml"))
            {
                var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
                ser.WriteObject(fs, people);
            }

            List<Person> people2;
            using (var fs = File.OpenRead("Test.xml"))
            {
                var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
                people2 = (List<Person>)ser.ReadObject(fs);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Are these daves the same dave?");
            Console.WriteLine("List dave, bob's friend - {0}", ReferenceEquals(people2[2], people2[0].Friends[1]));
            Console.WriteLine("Bob's firend, scott's friend - {0}", ReferenceEquals(people2[0].Friends[1], people2[1].Friends[0]));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {
            Friends = new List<Person>();
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Person> Friends { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Try running the above test program with `IsRefrence = false` or without the parameter (it defaults to false), it will output `false` for the tests of being the same object. However if you set it to `IsRefrence = false` it will output `true` for the tests of being the same object.

**EDIT:** One important note, there is no way I know of to make `RefrenceEquals(people[0], people2[0])` to output `true`.